# Evaluating the integral $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a(1+x)^3+1}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, closed-form

How can I solve this integral?

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a(1+x)^3+1}}$$

where $a>0$.

I have tried by using Mathematica, but it fails. Someone has any sugestion?

Comment: It's eliptic integral. It can't be written as an elementary function.

Comment: For $x>0$ and $a>0$ the solution is $(1+x)\; _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2};\frac{4}{3};-a(1+x)^3 \right)$ which contains a hypergeometric function.